# Symplifying expressions with exponentials inside square root

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex

I have an expression
$$
\exp (i k x) \sqrt{y^2 \exp (-2 i k x)}
$$
When I put this in Mathematica and do `FullSimplift`, it gives

```
FullSimplify[Exp[I k x] Sqrt[Exp[-2 I k x] y^2]]
```

The output is
$$
e^{i k x} \sqrt{y^2 e^{-2 i k x}}
$$
Even if I give all proper assumptions $\{x,y, k\} \in \mathbb R$ and $ -\pi < k \leq \pi$ like this

```
FullSimplify[Exp[I k x] Sqrt[Exp[-2 I k x] y^2], {x, y, k} \[Element] Reals && -\[Pi] < k <= \[Pi]]
```

The output comes as
$$
\left| y\right|  e^{i k x} \sqrt{e^{-2 i k x}}
$$
But the exponentials should not be there anymore, the result should be only $\left| y\right|$.

**What simplification or assumptions to make, to get the desired result?**

Comment: Mathematica will not choose a branch of `Sqrt` for you. `Sqrt[z]` where `z` is complex is not unique.

Comment: @user67431 can I myself choose the branch for sqrt?

Answer (score 2):

Try `PowerExpand`

```
PowerExpand[Exp[I k x] Sqrt[Exp[-2 I  k x] y^2]]
(*y*)
```

Comment: What if $y$ is a -ve number?

Comment: @Galilean see help. It says `are correct in general only if c is an integer or a and b are positive real numbers.` and `in general disregards all issues of branches of multivalued functions,` You can use Assumptions on it.